# load script plugin wordpress external page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, external

From an external page .php, I want to read the post content with this code

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('news/wp-load.php');    
$page_id = $_GET['id'];  //Page ID
$page_data = get_page($page_id); ?>
<h1><?php echo $title = $page_data->post_title;  ?></h1>
<?php
$content = $page_data->post_content;
echo $date = $page_data->post_date;     
echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $content ); 
?>
```

How do I include the plugin script (javascript, css) I have installed?
I tried using `<?php get_header();?>` but it does not include them.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

`wp_enqueue_script('test', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'test.js', array('jquery'));`

the third parameter is the dependency, if it's a script that uses, for example jQuery, ih there are no dependencies, just remove the third parameter

for CSS:

`wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );`

the documentation:

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/

Comment: @user2077311 np :)